# Is there a way to make RMarkdown tabs to show even after adding Shiny runtime?

Tags: r, shiny, tabs, r-markdown

I am trying to create interactive RMarkdown document from scrach.
The problem that I am occuring is the following.

I would like to divide RMarkdown document content into tabs (it seems visually nicer to me), but when setting the `runtime: shiny` in YAML, the RMarkdown tabs dissapers.

So, when knitting

```
---
output:
  html_document
---

## Title {.tabset .tabset-fade}
Content above tabbed region.

### Tab 1 
Tab 1 content

### Tab 2
Tab 2 content
```

I can see tabs, but if switching to (and running)

```
---
output:
  html_document
runtime:shiny
---

## Title {.tabset .tabset-fade}
Content above tabbed region.

### Tab 1 
Tab 1 content

### Tab 2
Tab 2 content
```

tabs disappear.

Does anyone has a clue why that happens? And maybe know how to make tabs reappear?

I am using R version 3.5.1, RStudio Version 1.1.456 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3), and R packages shown bellow:

```
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1        compiler_3.5.1    prettyunits_1.0.2 prettydoc_0.2.1   bitops_1.0-6     
 [6] remotes_2.0.2     tools_3.5.1       digest_0.6.18     pkgbuild_1.0.3    pkgload_1.0.2    
[11] evaluate_0.13     memoise_1.1.0     rlang_0.3.1       cli_1.0.1         rstudioapi_0.8   
[16] curl_3.2          yaml_2.2.0        xfun_0.6          withr_2.1.2       stringr_1.4.0    
[21] knitr_1.22        desc_1.2.0        fs_1.2.7          devtools_2.0.2    rprojroot_1.3-2  
[26] glue_1.3.1        R6_2.3.0          processx_3.3.0    rmarkdown_1.12.4  RJSONIO_1.3-0    
[31] sessioninfo_1.1.1 callr_3.2.0       magrittr_1.5      backports_1.1.2   ps_1.3.0         
[36] htmltools_0.3.6   usethis_1.5.0     rsconnect_0.8.8   assertthat_0.2.0  stringi_1.4.3    
[41] RCurl_1.95-4.11   crayon_1.3.4
```

Thank a lot!
Mia

Comment: Interesting fact .. I would use `flexdashboard` https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/ to make tabs in shiny environment.

Comment: Using the `shiny_prerendered` runtime in the YAML header might fix the issue [rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny_prerendered.html](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny_prerendered.html)

Comment: @fawda123 , unfortunately no. It makes static file (error: `Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents`).

Comment: @J_F, thanks for your suggestion. Although it is not the thing I am looking for, it makes a good back up.

Comment: @Mia for what it's worth, I opened an issue on the GitHub page https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1577

Comment: @fawda123 yes, thanks. Looking forward to see the issue solved :)

Comment: @Mia I've sent a PR to fix this bug https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/pull/1587

Comment: I have already saw that. Thanks a lot! Enjoy your stickers :)

Answer (score 2):

This is now solved.

Installing (`devtools::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')`) the current [git](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown) version  of the `rmarkdown` package solves the problem.
(At present, the most recent commit is #d42b1cd1 .)

Thanks

1. @fawda123 for opening an issue on GitHub, and
2. @RLesur for proposing the [FIX](http://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/pull/1587), which is now accepted and merged into master.